# Vuejs, modificar el DOM luego de que se renderiza

Tags: html, vue.js

Ayuda con ese componentes, cunado intento agregar un nuevo elemento

al agregar texto predefinido, lo hace de manera correcta, pero al hacer que escuche algún evento externo para traer texto, el texto es recogido pero jamas se muestra en:

```
Vue.component('list-din',{
  template:`<div>
  <b-button v-on:click="agrega">Agregar</b-button>
    <b-list-group >
      <b-list-group-item v-for="(renglon, index) in this.renglones" v-bind:key="renglon.id"
      v-bind:title="renglon.opcion"
      v-on:remove="renglones.splice(index,1)" class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"><tinymce-estatico>{{renglon.opcion}}</tinymce-estatico>
      <b-badge variant="primary" pill>{{renglon.calificacion}}</b-badge>
      </b-list-group-item>
    </b-list-group>
  </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return{ renglones: [{calificacion:1,
      opcion: 'texto',
      id: this.nextID,
      }

    ],
    nextID : 0,
  };
  },
  methods:{
    llama(){
      Event.fire('trae-opcion');},
    agrega(opcion){
      this.renglones.push({calificacion:1,opcion: opcion,id:this.nextID});
      this.nextID+=1;
    }
  },
  created:function(){
    Event.listen('recive-opcion',function(opcion){
      this.agrega(opcion);
      console.log('chido');      
    });
  } ,
});
```

Comment: no veo el método "agrega", seria conveniente para ver de que manera agregas el item al arreglo

Comment: el metodo agrega esta declarado en methods, luego de llama

Comment: ¿Dónde estás "escuchando" el evento? Recordemos que para poder comunicarte con elementos padre es necesario emitir un evento y escucharlo.

No queda muy clara tu pregunta, te recomendaría que trataras de explicarla mejor.

Comment: muhcas gracias a todos por su ayuda, pero ya descubri mi error, la palabra reservada function no debe ser usada dentro de Eventos, se cambia por el operador () =>{};